# is it necessary to have same names for .c and .o files?

Tags: c, makefile, object-files

```
CC=gcc -Wall
CFLAGS = -Wno-pointer-sign
LDFLAGS= -lipq

all: mtu rtu obj

mtu: flexiBitw_mtu
rtu: flexiBitw_rtu

flexiBitw_mtu: packetCapture.o mtu_decodePkt.o encrypt_decrypt.o sha1.o crypt.o file_parse.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) packetCapture.o mtu_decodePkt.o encrypt_decrypt.o sha1.o crypt.o file_parse.o -o flexiBitw_mtu $(LDFLAGS)

flexiBitw_rtu: packetCapture.o rtu_decodePkt.o encrypt_decrypt.o sha1.o crypt.o file_parse.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) packetCapture.o rtu_decodePkt.o encrypt_decrypt.o sha1.o crypt.o file_parse.o -o flexiBitw_rtu $(LDFLAGS)

obj:
        rm -f *.o

packetCapture.o: packetCapture.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c packetCapture.c file_parse.c 
mtu_decodePkt.o: mtu_decodePkt.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DCOMPILE_MTU -c mtu_decodePkt.c
rtu_decodePkt.o: mtu_decodePkt.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DCOMPILE_RTU -c mtu_decodePkt.c
encrypt_decrypt.o: encrypt_decrypt.c sha1.c crypt.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c encrypt_decrypt.c sha1.c crypt.c

clean:
        rm -rf *.o flexiBitw_mtu
        rm -rf *.o flexiBitw_rtu
```

it gives output as :

```
gcc -Wall  -Wno-pointer-sign -c packetCapture.c file_parse.c    
gcc -Wall  -Wno-pointer-sign -DCOMPILE_MTU -c mtu_decodePkt.c
gcc -Wall  -Wno-pointer-sign -c encrypt_decrypt.c sha1.c crypt.c
gcc -Wall  -Wno-pointer-sign packetCapture.o mtu_decodePkt.o encrypt_decrypt.o sha1.o crypt.o file_parse.o -o flexiBitw_mtu -lipq
gcc -Wall  -Wno-pointer-sign -DCOMPILE_RTU -c mtu_decodePkt.c
gcc -Wall  -Wno-pointer-sign packetCapture.o rtu_decodePkt.o encrypt_decrypt.o sha1.o crypt.o file_parse.o -o flexiBitw_rtu -lipq
gcc: rtu_decodePkt.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [flexiBitw_rtu] Error 1
```

I am doing conditional compilation by enabling different macros in mtu_decodepkt.c file
but it is giving error rtu_decodePkt.o: No such file or directory. 
 I had to change the .o file name so that it should not coincide in making both the executables.

please reply ...

Comment: No, there's nothing stopping you from having any name you want for either the source or the object files. The file names are not related to the content at all, you can even have another suffix than `.o` for the object files if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler what you want the object file to be called:

```
rtu_decodePkt.o: mtu_decodePkt.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DCOMPILE_RTU -c mtu_decodePkt.c -o rtu_decodePkt.o
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary. You can use the `-o` option to GCC to specify the name of the object file and link .o files as you like.

But in that case you can only compile one `.c` file at a time.